# chamada da descrição (HOVER)

Tags: html, css

Como faço para exibir a descrição ao fazer o `hover` na `<img>`?

Gostaria que quando o usuário passa-se o mouse sobre uma imagem uma determinada descrição seja exibida, segue abaixo meu código:

```css
/* corpo professores */

section#corpo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.professores {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: #34495e;
  padding: 60px;
}

.professores h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.border {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #3498db;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.ps {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.ps a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 30px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ps a img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 0.4s all;
}

.ps a:hover>img {
  filter: none;
}

.section {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section:target {
  height: auto;
}

.name {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* fim corpo professores */
```

```html
<section id="corpo">
  <div class="professores">
    <h1>PROFESSORES</h1>
    <span class="border"></span>
    <div class="ps">
      <a href="#1"> <img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#2"> <img src="img/2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#3"> <img src="img/3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="1">
      <span class="name">JAMES ARTHUR</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <p>
        Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se você pretende usar uma passagem
        de Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="2">
      <span class="name">STEVE JOBS</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <p>
        Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se você pretende usar uma passagem
        de Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="3">
      <span class="name">BILL GATES</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <p>
        Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se você pretende usar uma passagem
        de Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<div class="fotos">
  <h3>fotos</h3>
  Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se você pretende usar uma passagem
  de Lorem Ipsum, precisa ter certeza de que não há algo embaraçoso escrito escondido no meio do texto. Todos os geradores de Lorem Ipsum na internet tendem a repetir pedaços predefinidos conforme necessário, fazendo deste o primeiro gerador de Lorem
  Ipsum autêntico da internet. Ele usa um dicionário com mais de 200 palavras em Latim combinado com um punhado de modelos de estrutura de frases para gerar um Lorem Ipsum com aparência razoável, livre de repetições, inserções de humor, palavras não características,
  etc.
</div>

<div class="contato" a id="cont">
  <h3>contatos</h3>
  O trecho padrão original de Lorem Ipsum, usado desde o século XVI, está reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. Seções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" de Cicero também foram reproduzidas abaixo em sua forma exata original, acompanhada
  das versões para o inglês da tradução feita por H. Rackham em 1914.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: O que vc quer amigo?

Comment: rrss nao me expressei direito, queria quando passar meu cursor pela img, abra a descriçao

Comment: Abrir como?.....

Comment: tipo no html teria a imagem la ai tenho a descrição, delas escondidas e ao passar o mouse por cima da imagem, aparecia a descrição, mas pela minhas linhas apenas redireciona, nao aparece descrição

Comment: Wagner se possível, por favor, altere a sua pergunta e coloque a dúvida no corpo dela, assim futuros usuários que possuírem a mesma dúvida poderão encontrá-la de forma mais simples.

Comment: `title` não te serve? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title
Procure também por *Popover*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagner teremos que ir por etapas.

Primeiro se vc está usando `:target` para chamar a descrição não teria como o `:hover` funcionar... então eu substitui o `:target` pelo `:hover` no exemplo.

Outra coisa. vc tem uma `<section>` e uma div com a classe section `<div class="section">` e acho que isso fez vc confundira umas coisas no CSS. Mas eu ajustei isso colocando `div.section {}` para não mexer muito no que vc já fez.

Estruturalmente tive que mexer no HTML para colocar as descrições das imagens dentro da sua `div.ps`. Dessa forma foi possível criar uma regra css `.ps > .img3:hover ~ #id3 {}` para mostrar a descrição no :hover sem precisar de JS ou jQuery.

Execute em "Página toda" para ver melhor o resultado já que o código ainda não está responsivo. ***OBS:*** Mexi o mínimo possível no sei código e o resultado vc pode ver abaixo:

```css
/* corpo professores */
section#corpo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.professores{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: #34495e;
    padding: 60px;
}

.professores h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.border{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 160px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #3498db;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.ps{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.ps a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 30px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.ps a img{
    width: 100%;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 0.4s all;
}

.ps a:hover > img{
    filter: none;
}

div.section{
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* div.section:target{
    height: auto;
} */

.ps > .img1:hover ~ #id1 {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.ps > .img2:hover ~ #id2 {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.ps > .img3:hover ~ #id3 {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


.name{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
}
/* fim corpo professores */
```

```html
<section id="corpo">
    <div class="professores">
        <h1>PROFESSORES</h1>
        <span class="border"></span>
        <div class="ps">
            <a class="img1" href="#id1">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="img2" href="#id2">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="img3" href="#id3">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt="">
            </a>


            <div class="section" id="id1">
                <span class="name">JAMES ARTHUR</span>
                <span class="border"></span>
                <p>
                    Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por
                    inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se
                    você pretende usar uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="id2">
                <span class="name">STEVE JOBS</span>
                <span class="border"></span>
                <p>
                    Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por
                    inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se
                    você pretende usar uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="id3">
                <span class="name">BILL GATES</span>
                <span class="border"></span>
                <p>
                    Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por
                    inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se
                    você pretende usar uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>

<div class="fotos">
    <h3>fotos</h3>
    Existem muitas variações disponíveis de passagens de Lorem Ipsum, mas a maioria sofreu algum tipo de alteração, seja por
    inserção de passagens com humor, ou palavras aleatórias que não parecem nem um pouco convincentes. Se você pretende usar
    uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, precisa ter certeza de que não há algo embaraçoso escrito escondido no meio do texto. Todos
    os geradores de Lorem Ipsum na internet tendem a repetir pedaços predefinidos conforme necessário, fazendo deste o primeiro
    gerador de Lorem Ipsum autêntico da internet. Ele usa um dicionário com mais de 200 palavras em Latim combinado com um
    punhado de modelos de estrutura de frases para gerar um Lorem Ipsum com aparência razoável, livre de repetições, inserções
    de humor, palavras não características, etc.
</div>

<div class="contato" a id="cont">
    <h3>contatos</h3>
    O trecho padrão original de Lorem Ipsum, usado desde o século XVI, está reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. Seções 1.10.32
    e 1.10.33 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" de Cicero também foram reproduzidas abaixo em sua forma exata original,
    acompanhada das versões para o inglês da tradução feita por H. Rackham em 1914.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: show de bola hugocsl, funcionou, era esse hover que precisava, vallew...